# Why do I get different connection speeds when using local vs public IP?

Tags: networking, dns

My home server has a dynamic DNS service attached to the public IP, and I usually connect through it even when at home. However, I just noticed that SFTP'ing through the public IP has a huge impact in speed (100MB/s v.s. 3MB/s on a gigabit network), when compared to an SFTP through the private network's IP. Why does this happen? Why can't the switch/router optimize the connection? Is this a synonym of a low-quality router? Is this solvable?

Comment: Compare the two `tracert` or `traceroute` outputs for a hint as to why you see the drastic speed differences . . .

Comment: @ernie, `tracert` isn't going to help much.. you'll just see one hop either way, unless you have a way to trace a SFTP packet that is going to be forwarded by the router (tracert packets aimed at the router will never make it to the server behind the router).

Comment: Yes, both `traceroute`s give a single hop.

Comment: Interesting, I was guessing it would show the route going out and back . . .

Comment: @ernieI think what's happening is that if he tracert's the external IP, it's going to stop at the router - one hop away from him.  If he pings by the internal LAN IP, it will go directly to that device - one hop away.

Answer (score 1):

"Is this a symptom of a low-quality router?"  Probably, at least it certainly can be.  You didn't tell us the router you're using, so I'm going to assume it's a SOHO-level "Internet router".

When you access the outside IP address from inside you are making the router do a lot more work (look up Haripin NAT routing, perhaps start with [Wikipedia's entry on it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning)), and therefore much more  processing of the traffic is required.  Many low-cost SOHO "internet routers" do no processing/routing on the LAN side, it's (basically) just a switch on the LAN side. So with devices on the LAN side, little to no actual routing takes place, so little to no processing power is required, and so no speed degradation.

Most low-cost, SOHO-level routers I've seen don't even support hairpin.

Also, many of the SOHO routers that represent themselves as "GB routers" only do proper GB on the LAN side.

So, to determine for sure - replace the router with a different (better) one and see if it makes a difference.